# Python: Evaluating a board position using stockfish from the python-chess library

Tags: python, python-chess

I am trying to create an engine but my evaluation function is terrible so I decided to use stockfish to evaluate it for me.

```
import chess
import chess.engine

def stockfish_evaluation(board, time_limit = 0.01):
    engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("stockfish/stockfish_10_x64")
    result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=time_limit))
    return result.info["score"]

board = chess.Board("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1")
result = stockfish_evaluation(board)
print(result)
```

but it prints out:

```
KeyError: 'score'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong function, it should be `engine.analyse` not `engine.play`

```
import chess
import chess.engine

def stockfish_evaluation(board, time_limit = 0.01):
    engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("stockfish_10_x64")
    result = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=time_limit))
    return result['score']

board = chess.Board("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1")
result = stockfish_evaluation(board)
print(result)

#+58
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `engine.close()` line?